# Can you use ーられない to express that something is unbearable?

Tags: grammar, nuances

Perhaps ーづらい is more appropriate in this case? For instance:

> *I can't look (because it's unbearable)*
>   [辛]{つら}くて見られない

Maybe a more natural way to express the above?

> *[it is] unbearable to look at*
>   見[辛]{づら}い

Without the ーづらい

> *Horror films are so scary I can't watch them*
>   ホラー映画は怖すぎて観られない

Comment: 怖すぎた why ～た here?

Answer (score 4):

辛くて見られない is okay, but when actually facing with something terrible, people more commonly say 辛くて見ていられない. You can also just say 見ていられない without 辛くて. (辛くて)直視できない is also common in writing.

見づらい is not appropriate. It usually means being physically hard to see due to things like bad writing, low image quality, weak light, etc.

Answer (score 2):

辛くて見られない and 見辛い don't have the same meaning. The former means "It is so painful that I can't look at it", and the latter means "hard to see", "indistinct".

A verb + づらい means "hard to verb" like 走りづらい (hard to run.)

In addition, Goo dictionary says that 見辛い means 見るに耐えない (can't stand looking at) and gives the example 金をめぐる争いは見辛い, but I feel it isn't common.